# Why not always target "es3" in tsconfig?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Since ES3 is the oldest standard that TypeScript can compile to that means it should have the widest possible browser support.

I don't care what the compiled JS looks like, so why would I ever want to compile to a newer version of JS?

Doesn't a higher target just reduce the number of browsers that can run my app?

Comment: One negative of ES3 is that it blows up the filesize. I can imagine it could also be slower given that modern features will have to be emulated although I have no idea if this is significant.

Comment: Not all features can be truly compiled down https://mariusschulz.com/blog/downlevel-iteration-for-es3-es5-in-typescript. You also need polyfills for several features that TS won't emit for you. Just use browserslist for sane defaults.